# Trouble Installing PythonMagick on Windows 7: "Package missing..."

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda, pythonmagick

When I try installing PythonMagick on Windows 7 via a `conda install -c melund pythonmagick=0.9.10` command, I get this error:

> Package missing in current win-32 channels:
>   - pythonmagick 0.9.10*

What do I need to do?

Comment: have you tried without the version number?

Comment: This package is only available from that channel for win-64. You cannot install it into 32-bit conda.

Comment: Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick

Comment: I tried without the version number, and I get this error:

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- python 3.5*
- pythonmagick

Comment: I uninstalled my 32-bit python and installed the 64-bit python, and it's still not working.

Comment: cgohlke,

When you say try that website, I'm not sure what you mean to try it.  What needs to be done?  I just see tons of links, not sure which one to download or what to do with it.

Comment: Never mind, used "pip install <filename>", and it worked.  Thanks, cgohlke!  How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: How do I install it on anaconda? I tried this command but its not working..